# Accessing using uploaded Sqlite db's using Django ORM

Tags: python, database, django, sqlite

In Django, is there a way to open any sqlite database file.  Make use of the Django ORM, and then close the database.  Something like:

```
def my_view(request):
    song1 = Song.objects.get(id=4)   # Using normal postgres db

    temp_db = open_db('/path/to/my/db.sqlite')
    song2 = Song.objects.get(id=4, using=temp_db)
    song2.title = song1.title
    song2.save()
    temp_db.close()

    return HttpResponse(temp_db.as_binary(), mime_type='application/x-sqlite3')
```

In short: my Django web application needs to be able to synchronise with some 3rd party desktop software which stores data in a sqlite database that is stored on the users local computer.  The synchronisation only needs to be one way.  That is, changes in the web application would update the local sqlite database.

I was thinking I could get away with using the dropbox api to sync the sqlite database.  Each user would have their own dropbox database synchronised.

Would it be much easier to do something like this and not use the ORM at all?

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('/path/to/db.sqlite')
c = conn.cursor()
for row in c.execute('SELECT * FROM Song'):
    print row
```

Comment: waiting for answer... :p

Comment: [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/multi-db/) May be useful

Comment: Thanks @ErDmKo, I looked into that before posting this questions.  I'm happy to be corrected, but I don't believe that will work.  Each database needs to be specified in the settings file.  Whereas each of my users may of one or more database files to synchronise with.

I'm not locked into doing it this way, so if there is any completely different way to solve this case, I'm happy to give that a go too.